# HowTo install custom nodejs version (14.2.0) on AWS Opsworks Chef 11/12 stack

Tags: node.js, aws-opsworks, cookbook

I have a nodejs express app that makes use of some ES6 features, so it needs nodejs way above 0.12.18. But the AWS Opsworks Chef 11 stack only offers NodeJs up to 0.12.18.

I tried using my own custom cookbook/recipe and created 'opsworks_nodejs/attributes/customize.rb':

```
normal[:opsworks_nodejs][:version] = '14.2.0'
normal[:opsworks_nodejs][:prefix_url][:node] = 'https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_14.x/el/7/x86_64/'
normal[:opsworks_nodejs][:rpm] = "nodejs-14.2.0-1nodesource.x86_64.rpm"
normal[:opsworks_nodejs][:rpm_url] = "https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_14.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-14.2.0-1nodesource.x86_64.rpm"
```

But the setup fails and the logs show me that it tried to download a file that does not exist. It ignores my changes (except for the version part):

```
https://opsworks-instance-assets-eu-west-1.s3.amazonaws.com/packages/amazon/2018.03/opsworks-nodejs-14.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I wonder if there is a way to use the Chef 11 stack just like it is and only change the nodejs version to 14.2.0, as i am used to all the other recipes in use there, especially the deploy mechanism. All i want to differ is the node.js version.

If not, am i right in assuming that i have to use a Chef 12 stack that doesn't have those recipes pre-set? What would be the easiest way to just get nodejs 14.2.0 installed and still be able to use the convenient "Deploy"-feature the Chef 11 stack offers?

Comment: What's the version of `chef-client`? Do you have privileges on the Chef server?

Comment: I am using Amazon Web Services opsworks. I am not sure where to look or the chef-client version. But i am pretty sure its Chef 11.10 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-chef11.html)

Comment: `chef-client --version` should show the version. Just trying to explore the possibility of working around the OpsWorks system.

Comment: I can ssh to that instance. And after both 'sudo su' and 'sudo su deploy', the 'chef-client' command cannot be found.

Comment: I remember seeing a [recommendation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/welcome_opscm.html) on using `chef-client` v14.10.9.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, adding this as an answer. There is a [recommendation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/welcome_opscm.html) to use "at least" v14.10.9.

> The minimum supported version of chef-client on nodes associated with an AWS OpsWorks for Chef Automate server is 13.x. We recommend running at least 14.10.9, or the most current, stable chef-client version.

If you can have Chef client v14+ available, then you should be able to use the [nodejs](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nodejs) cookbook from Chef supermarket. Using Berkshelf (`Berksfile`) we should be then able to pull this as a dependency.

```rb
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook 'nodejs'
```

**The sequence usually is:**

Add dependency for community cookbook in `metadata.rb`:

```rb
name 'my_cookbook'
version '0.1.0'

depends 'nodejs', '~> 7.3.0'
```

Update / set the required attributes in `attributes/default.rb` or may be `customize.rb`:

```rb
default['nodejs']['install_method'] = 'binary'

default['nodejs']['version'] = '14.2.0'
default['nodejs']['binary']['checksum'] = '3307d8b95014e78b43f85242a03fe3b28edfb90cc15e1d26393dcbbc51d05c8e'
```

Then in a `recipes/default.rb`:

```rb
include_recipe 'nodejs'
```

Comment: To me it looks like AWS Opsworks only offers Chef 11 and 12. Switching to another Chef-version (if possible at all) would require me to build all other coobooks and recipes myself in order to mimic the default Chef 11 AWS Opsworks default coobooks and recipes.

Not worth it for me. There seem to be other ways to have nodejs-14.2.0 instances on AWS.

Thanks for your efforts anyway!